# Safe and fast way to move a partition to begining of disk?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, disk-utility, partition-magic

How can I move a partition to beginning of the disk in a fast and safe way?

Comment: more info needed. Why? What's on the disk? What file systems?

Comment: Thanks, There is Windows XP installed on the first partition and Windows 7 on the last partition, I want to remove XP and move Windwow 7 as the first partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be safest to delete the first partition, resize the remainder as you wish, and then recreate the first partition and copy the Windows 7 files into that partition.  I don't know of a Windows tool for this, but an easy way to do it is to use the [Gparted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php).  Gparted uses the Parted library, which is a widely known, tested and safe tool for partition management (though no tool can be fully safe of course).

Answer (score 1):

Run a backup on windows 7, restore it to the first partition, then delete the old windows 7 partition and resize once you know it works. That way, If something goes wrong, you have a backup ;p.

Comment: +1 Thanks, yep that way at least I have the backup.